# android development - register and unregister onClick, Cannot resolve method

Tags: java, android

Consider this code:

```
package com.example.savag.bcapplication;

import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{
    //define global variable types
    int counter=0;
    String strcounter;
    int buttoncounter=0;
    String strbcounter;
    TextView dynamicheader;
    //Define the sensor Manager
    SensorManager sm;

    //Define the Motion Sensor objects
    Sensor accelerometer;
    Sensor gravity;
    Sensor gyroscope;
    Sensor uncalgyro;
    Sensor lineaccel;
    Sensor rotatevector;
    Sensor sigmotion;
    Sensor stepcounter;
    Sensor stepdetector;
    //Define the changing Motion Sensor text values
    TextView gyrosense;
    TextView uncalgyrosense;
    TextView acceleration;
    TextView gravitysense;
    TextView lineaccelsense;
    TextView rotatesense;
    TextView sigmotionsense; //In order to make use of this, use onTrigger event
    TextView stepstaken;
    TextView stepdetected; //In order to make use of this, use onTrigger event

    //Define the position sensor objects
    Sensor gamerotatevector;

    //Define the changing Position sensor objects
    TextView gamerotatesense;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // variables final static
        final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.motbut_unpressed);
        final ImageView topbar2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.topbarmain);
        final ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.posbut_unpressed);
        final ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.envbut_unpressed);
        final LinearLayout babcockandfield = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.babcocklayout);
        final ImageButton arrowup = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.uparrow);
        final ImageButton arrowdown = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.downarrow);
        final ImageView navbar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.infospace);
        //Global counter variables
        counter = 0;
        strcounter = Integer.toString(counter);
        buttoncounter = 0;
        strbcounter = Integer.toString(buttoncounter);
        //Set Nav bar invisible for now
        arrowup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        arrowdown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        navbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        HandlerThread mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("sensorThread");

        mHandlerThread.start();

        final Handler handler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());


        button1.setOnClickListener( //This is for the motion button
                new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        buttoncounter=1;
                        strbcounter = Integer.toString(buttoncounter); // maybe need and on counter listener
                        //change colour of pressed button
                        button1.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.motionbutton_pressed, null));
                        topbar2.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.topbarmotion, null));
                        bcandf.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.logoandbarmotion, null));
                        //make sure the other two buttons are normal again
                        button2.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.positionbutton_normal, null));
                        button3.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.envirobutton_normal, null));
                        //make the arrows and infospace appear
                        arrowup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        arrowdown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        navbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //Dynamic text appearance
                        //set the text inside infospace
                        //dynamicheader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
        );
        button2.setOnClickListener( //This is for the position button
                new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        buttoncounter=2;
                        strbcounter = Integer.toString(buttoncounter); // maybe need and on counter listener
                        //Change colour of pressed button
                        button2.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.positionbutton_pressed, null));
                        topbar2.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.topbarposition, null));
                        bcandf.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.logoandbaralternate, null));
                        //make sure the other two buttons are normal again
                        button1.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.motionbutton_normal, null));
                        button3.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.envirobutton_normal, null));
                        //make the arrows and the infospace appear
                        arrowup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        arrowdown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        navbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //Dynamic text appearance
                        //set the text inside infospace
                        //dynamicheader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
        );
        button3.setOnClickListener( //This is for the environment button
                new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        buttoncounter=3;
                        strbcounter = Integer.toString(buttoncounter); // maybe need and on counter listener
                        //change colour of pressed button
                        button3.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.envirobutton_pressed, null));
                        topbar2.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.topbarenviro, null));
                        bcandf.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.logoandbaralternate, null));
                        //make sure the other two buttons are normal again
                        button1.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.motionbutton_normal, null));
                        button2.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.positionbutton_normal, null));
                        //make the arrows and the infospace appear
                        arrowup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        arrowdown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        navbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //Dynamic text appearance
                        //set the text inside infospace
                       // dynamicheader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
        );
        arrowup.setOnClickListener( //This is for the up arrow
                new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        if (strcounter.equals("0")||(strcounter.equals("10")))
                        {
                            //do nothing if strcounter is 0
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            counter--; //how many times
                            strcounter = Integer.toString(counter);
                            //et1.setText(strcounter);
                            //now lets set text accordingly
                            //First we need to set in sequential order and also check button we are on
                            if (strcounter.equals("1")) {
                                ////////
                                if (strbcounter.equals("1")) { // Check which button 1 is motion {
                                    //Motion button going on
                                    gravitysense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    acceleration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    //set the text inside infospace
                                    dynamicheader.setText("Acceleration:");
                                    //Now we need to register the sensors and whatnot
                                    accelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
                                    sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, handler);
                                    //acceleration.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + "\nY: " + event.values[1] + "\nZ: " + event.values[2]);
                                }
                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("2")) {
                                ////////
                                if (strbcounter.equals("1")) { // Check which button 1 is motion {
                                    //Get rid of the last values and set the one we are using
                                    acceleration.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    gravitysense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    //set the text inside infospace
                                    dynamicheader.setText("Gravity Sensor:");
                                    //gravitysense.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + "\nY: " + event.values[1] + "\nZ: " + event.values[2]);
                                }
                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("3")) {
                                ////////
                                if (strbcounter.equals("1")) { // Check which button 1 is motion
                                    //Get rid of the last values and set the one we are using
                                    gravitysense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    gyrosense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    //set the text inside infospace
                                    dynamicheader.setText("Gyroscope:");
                                    //gyrosense.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + "\nY: " + event.values[1] + "\nZ: " + event.values[2]);
                                }
                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("4")) {
                                ////////
                                if (strbcounter.equals("1")) { // Check which button 1 is motion
                                    //Get rid of the last values and set the one we are using
                                    gyrosense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    uncalgyrosense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    //set the text inside infospace
                                    dynamicheader.setText("Raw Gyroscope:");
                                    //uncalgyrosense.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + "\nY: " + event.values[1] + "\nZ: " + event.values[2] +
                                    //        "\nX: " + event.values[3] + "\nY: " + event.values[4] + "\nZ: " + event.values[5]);
                                }

                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("5")) {
                                ////////
                                if (strbcounter.equals("1")) { // Check which button 1 is motion
                                    uncalgyrosense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    lineaccelsense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    //set the text inside infospace
                                    dynamicheader.setText("Linear Sensor:");
                                    //lineaccelsense.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + "\nY: " + event.values[1] + "\nZ: " + event.values[2]);
                                }
                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("6")) {
                                ////////
                                if (strbcounter.equals("1")) { // Check if motion has been pressed
                                    lineaccelsense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    rotatesense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    //set the text inside infospace
                                    dynamicheader.setText("Rotation Sensors");
                                    //rotatesense.setText("X: " + event.values[0] + "\nY: " + event.values[1] + "\nZ: " + event.values[2]);
                                }
                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("7")) {
                                ////////
                                if (strbcounter.equals("1")) { // Check which button 1 is motion
                                    rotatesense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    sigmotionsense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    //set the text inside infospace
                                    dynamicheader.setText("Significant Motion Sensor:");
                                   // sigmotionsense.setText(event.values[0] + "");
                                }

                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("8")) {
                                ////////
                                if (strbcounter.equals("1")) { // Check which button 1 is motion
                                    sigmotionsense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    stepstaken.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    //set the text inside infospace
                                    dynamicheader.setText("Step Counter:");
                                }
                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("9")) {
                                ////////
                                if (strbcounter.equals("1")) { // Check which button 1 is motion
                                    stepstaken.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    stepdetected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    //set the text inside infospace
                                    dynamicheader.setText("Step Detector:");
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        }
                    }
        );
        arrowdown.setOnClickListener( //This is for the down arrow
                new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        if (strcounter.equals("9")||(strcounter.equals("0"))) // might be that we need to add a second variable for mot,pos,env
                        {
                            //Do nothing as we have reached the bottom
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            counter++; //how many times
                            strcounter = Integer.toString(counter);
                            //et1.setText(strcounter);
                            //now lets set text accordingly
                            if (strcounter.equals("8")) {
                                ////////
                                stepstaken.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                stepdetected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                //set the text inside infospace
                                dynamicheader.setText("Steps Taken:");

                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("7")) {
                                ////////
                                sigmotionsense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                stepstaken.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                //set the text inside infospace
                                dynamicheader.setText("Significant Motion:");
                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("6")) {
                                ////////
                                rotatesense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                sigmotionsense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                //set the text inside infospace
                                dynamicheader.setText("Rotation Sensor:");
                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("5")) {
                                ////////
                                lineaccelsense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                rotatesense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                //set the text inside infospace
                                dynamicheader.setText("Linear Acceleration:");
                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("4")) {
                                ////////
                                uncalgyrosense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                lineaccelsense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                //set the text inside infospace
                                dynamicheader.setText("Raw Gyroscope:");

                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("3")) {
                                ////////
                                gyrosense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                uncalgyrosense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                //set the text inside infospace
                                dynamicheader.setText("Gyroscope:");

                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("2")) {
                                ////////
                                gravitysense.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                gyrosense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                //set the text inside infospace
                                dynamicheader.setText("Gravity Sensor:");
                            }
                            if (strcounter.equals("1")) {
                                ////////
                                acceleration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                gravitysense.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                //set the text inside infospace
                                dynamicheader.setText("Acceleration:");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

The app basically listens to a bunch of buttons, and sets some visible and invisible etc, for adaptive UI based on buttons.
Next to save memory, and so that the SensorEventListener isn't listening to every single sensor at the same time it's enclosed within a OnClick method.

The intention is to register and unregister on click.
First arrow registers *accelerometer*, then the next arrow will unregister accelerometer and register another sensor.
Then in `SensorChanged` grab the event info for display.

First of all I tried without any handler and just wrote like this:

```
sm.registerListener.(this, accelerometer,   SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

This flagged up the following error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'registerListener(anonymous  
android.view.View.OnClickListener, android.hardware.Sensor, int)'
```

So I thought that perhaps it needs a handler, so as the updated code shows I added an handler, this needed to be set as Final, because android studio flagged up an error. So I added the code for the handler that you can see under the OnCreate method. Inserting the handler brought up this:

```
Cannot resolve method 'registerListener(anonymous 
android.view.View.OnClickListener, android.hardware.Sensor, int, 
android.os.Handler)'
```

I'm unsure why this is so difficult to do. I want the sensor manager to only listen to the sensor that I need it too, if and when I select one. Any help or clarification on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MainActivity.this` instead of `this` as first parameter in `registerListener` and `unregisterListener` .like:

```
sm.registerListener.(MainActivity.this, accelerometer, 
                               SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

reason is inside onClick method `this` refer to the context on `onClick` method instead of `MainActivity` in which you are implementing `SensorEventListener`

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that